# How to make checkbuttons add sql query where conditions

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

I have a simple slq select query. And i have 6 checkbuttons

```
self.NAME = tk.IntVar(value=1)
self.PRICE = tk.IntVar(value=1)


self.Checkbutton1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="NAME",
                                           variable=self.NAME,
                                           onvalue=1, offvalue=0,)

self.Checkbutton2 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="PRICE",
                                           variable=self.PRICE,
                                           onvalue=1, offvalue=0)

...4 more buttons like that...
```

I want execute my select query and add where conditions for each buttons checked.

```
db.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE informations LIKE 'NAME' OR LIKE 'PRICE' OR LIKE ...for each buttons")
```

I set IntVar(value=1) for have them selected automatically

How can I do that?

Comment: by adding the where clauses to the text and filling the tuple up for the parameters

Comment: You build a function that takes the base SQL string and then per check box concatenate on the conditions as a where for the first condition and then "and" conditions after that. This is nor a question of concatenation so you should have more than enough resources for this one on SO.